# Deform the mesh by armature located aside the mesh

Tags: mesh, bones

Can i deform the mesh by armature located aside the mesh?
I spent several experiments with origin but i noticed that it does not affect the way that I expected. Mesh follow up the bone but relative to the center of selected bone. If push the mesh to armature it's seems right. But i need make they apart
[image: Cube's origin located along Armature's origin, but Cube's mesh move left]

[image: Cube's origin move right because i move it with mesh in object mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked, but this could achieve a similar effect: set two identical armatures, one inside the object performing the deform, one "external"  (aside) driving the deform, each internal bone connected to its external peer through copy rotation constraints...

[image]

example file: 
[image]